# How to create DataSource with Apache DBCP 1.4?

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

I'm trying this:

```
final PoolableConnectionFactory factory = new PoolableConnectionFactory(
  new DriverManagerConnectionFactory("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb", "sa", ""),
  new GenericObjectPool(null),
  null,
  "SELECT 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_USERS",
  true,
  false,
  Connection.TRANSACTION_NONE
);
DataSource ds = new PoolingDataSource(factory.getPool());
ds.getConnection();
```

To no avail, exception is thrown:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Could not create a validated object, cause: Invalid argument in JDBC call
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1191)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your PoolableConnectionFactory like this

```
PoolableConnectionFactory factory = new PoolableConnectionFactory(
  new DriverManagerConnectionFactory("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb", "sa", ""), 
  new GenericObjectPool(null), 
  null, null, false, true);
```

And check if it works that way. Then check if the extra parameter related to transaction is valid in the DBCP version or not.

Comment: I looked briefly at the definition of the PoolableConnectionFactory class and didn't find a constructor including the parameters you setted. Just guessed that the standard declaration would work. http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/PoolableConnectionFactory.html